# Converting bits of a byte to single bits and back

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, stm32

I have the struct below

```
typedef struct fpButtons {

  /**     BYTE 0         **/        
  uint8_t       button_1:1;       
  uint8_t       button_2:1;
  uint8_t       button_3:1;
  uint8_t       button_4:1;
  uint8_t       button_5:1;
  uint8_t       button_6:1;
  uint8_t       button_7:1;
  uint8_t       button_8:1;

  /** And BYTE 2 which I didn't paste to save SO's space lol **/
  // button_9:1 to button_16:1
} FP_BUTTONS;
```

And this function that gives an unsigned integer, which its bits should build the struct above

```
void FP_UpdateData(FP_BUTTONS *data, uint8_t b1, uint8_t b2) 
{
  data->button_1 = (b1 & ( 1 << 1 )) >> 1;
  data->button_2 = (b1 & ( 1 << 2 )) >> 2;
  data->button_3 = (b1 & ( 1 << 3 )) >> 3;
  data->button_4 = (b1 & ( 1 << 4 )) >> 4;
  data->button_5 = (b1 & ( 1 << 5 )) >> 5;
  data->button_6 = (b1 & ( 1 << 6 )) >> 6;
  data->button_7 = (b1 & ( 1 << 7 )) >> 7;
  data->button_8 = (b1 & ( 1 << 8 )) >> 8;

  //Do the same thing for button 9 to 16

}
```

Now after storing, I have to send it somewhere else :

```
void APP_Send(){

  uint8_t packet[2];

  packet[0] = *((uint8_t*) &FP_BUTTONS_Data);
  packet[1] = *(((uint8_t*) &FP_BUTTONS_Data)+1);    

  //Send stuff away.....
}
```

Despite all the effort, none of the codes above seems to work. I am doing this on an embedded processor and its really hard to debug. I wonder if some C-Guru guys can tell me what can be wrong with this codes?

Comment: Shouldn't your first shift be `1<<0` instead? (Not a solution, because it still ought to do *something* - wrong, but still.)

Comment: Bit fields can apparently be a source of major grief when it comes to portability or even within a single platform with endianness. It might be worth avoiding them in favor of just doing the bitwise logic yourself. That said, if they work fine and you're okay with that, I really recommend a union here with `fpButtons` and `uint8_t`. Then you don't have to bother extracting/packing bits. Otherwise it seems especially pointless to use bit fields when you're just going to be doing all this bitwise extraction anyway.

Comment: @Ike I really cant go with the union solution, because it is necessary for other parts of project.

Comment: @SaeidYazdani How so? You can still get your original `fpButton` field out of the union for the other parts that depend on that.

Comment: @Ike oops you are right!

Comment: You should use a macro instead of writing out all those bit shifts.

Comment: @Ike: Isn't that union trick UB in c++? Although it's not clear whether this is a c or c++ program

Comment: @MikeMB Generally I think anything dealing with reinterpreting bits and bytes is in danger of being UB, but I think this kind of union is one of those categories of UB (if UB) that tend to be consistent well enough in a de-facto kind of way. Not sure if that's a good answer: I'm used to having to blur the line between C/C++-type coding to interface with C APIs, and see a lot of undefined things go by that are often done anyway by necessity.

Comment: @ike, MikeMB: Such a union is actually at least implementation defined for C, too, as the ordering is not fixed by the standard. For the apparent useage here, this is actually uncommon - at best. You would normally use normal scalars with bitops.

Comment: @ike,Olaf: Actually, I hoped the answer would be: "No, even in c++ it's only implementation defined". That would solve a similar problem of mine. Although I try to avoid it, I've no problem with IB, because I can write unittests and read documentation to verify that it's behaving as expected. UB is more scary, as it might break in different contexts or from one compiler version to another without notice.

Comment: @MikeMB I'm curious too as to whether this would be IB or UB. I'm afraid I'm not much of a language lawyer, and also rely on paranoid testing and lots of assertions whenever I'm forced into making seemingly unsafe or non-portable assumptions about bit/byte reps. It's something I'm often forced into doing a lot working with C APIs that do a number of scary things from casting function pointers to/from void*, striding over interleaved data, flattening away structure representations and pretending they're just contiguous buffers storing their fields with predetermined alignment, etc.

Comment: @Ike what is IB/UB? It turned out to be a topic of discussion for you guys!

Comment: @SaeidYazdani Implementation-defined vs. undefined behavior. Basically we're just wondering around the portability of this kind of code.

Comment: @Ike well this code is supposed to run only on STMF10X microcontrollers. with specific tool chains so no worries. In case of x86/64 architecture then I guess it will be up to compiler, that would be my uneducated gues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bits are 0-indexed, but you coded the shifts as if bits were 1-indexed instead.  You have to use `0` through `7` for the shifts on a `uint8_t`.

Also, the right-shifts can be removed.

Try this:

```
void FP_UpdateData(FP_BUTTONS *data, uint8_t b1, uint8_t b2) 
{
  data->button_1 = (b1 & ( 1 << 0 )) != 0;
  data->button_2 = (b1 & ( 1 << 1 )) != 0;
  data->button_3 = (b1 & ( 1 << 2 )) != 0;
  data->button_4 = (b1 & ( 1 << 3 )) != 0;
  data->button_5 = (b1 & ( 1 << 4 )) != 0;
  data->button_6 = (b1 & ( 1 << 5 )) != 0;
  data->button_7 = (b1 & ( 1 << 6 )) != 0;
  data->button_8 = (b1 & ( 1 << 7 )) != 0;

  //Do the same thing for button 9 to 16
}

void APP_Send()
{
  uint8_t packet[2];

  uint8_t *data = (uint8_t*) &FP_BUTTONS_Data;
  packet[0] = data[0];
  packet[1] = data[1];

  //Send stuff away.....
}
```

With that said, all of this manual shifting is unnecessary if you wrap the struct data in `union`s:

```
typedef struct fpButtons {

  /**     BYTE 0         **/        
  union {
    struct {
      uint8_t       button_1:1;       
      uint8_t       button_2:1;
      uint8_t       button_3:1;
      uint8_t       button_4:1;
      uint8_t       button_5:1;
      uint8_t       button_6:1;
      uint8_t       button_7:1;
      uint8_t       button_8:1;
    };
    uint8_t         rawbuttons_1;
  };

  /**     BYTE 1         **/        
  union {
    struct {
      uint8_t       button_9:1;       
      uint8_t       button_10:1;
      uint8_t       button_11:1;
      uint8_t       button_12:1;
      uint8_t       button_13:1;
      uint8_t       button_14:1;
      uint8_t       button_15:1;
      uint8_t       button_16:1;
    };
    uint8_t         rawbuttons_2;
  };

} FP_BUTTONS;

void FP_UpdateData(FP_BUTTONS *data, uint8_t b1, uint8_t b2) 
{
  data->rawbuttons_1 = b1;
  data->rawbuttons_2 = b2;
}

void APP_Send()
{
  uint8_t packet[2];

  packet[0] = FP_BUTTONS_Data.rawbuttons_1;
  packet[1] = FP_BUTTONS_Data.rawbuttons_2;

  //Send stuff away.....
}
```

Comment: Just a quick question, as the alternative is better: does yours make more sense over using `data->button_1 = (b1 >> 0) &1;` (and so on) in the top function, because that trades something like `test`+`setnz` against a `shr`+`and`? Seeing this, I must have used such a construct hundreds of times - but I imagine shifting is more expensive.

Comment: Assigning to `rawbuttons_1` will set all 8 bits at the same time, no bit manipulation is needed, just a single `MOV` assignment.  Assigning to `button_1` will set just that one bit and not the other 7 bits, so bit manipulation is used and would be more expensive.

Comment: Yes, that's the better alternative. I was referring to your construction `data->button_1 = (b1 & ( 1 << 0 )) != 0;`, which on first sight seems more complicated than mine, using a single data shift. (By the way, I may have answered my own question alteady.)

Comment: your original code was using 2 shifts to get a boolean result, my example was using 1 shift and 1 comparison instead. A comparison is less work than a shift.  And a decent compiler should be able to optimize out `<< 0` since it is basically a no-op.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider changing your approach if you're essentially saving two octets into the custom bit-packed structure only to pull those two octets back out to send them somewhere else.

Assuming all your bit fields are 1 bit wide (as is the case in your example) you can use bit shifting to access the values (which the compiler will do for you anyway) like such:

```
/* Button shift values */
typedef enum
{
    BUTTON_1 = 0,
    BUTTON_2 = 1,
    ...
    BUTTON_16 = 15,
} button_t;

void FP_UpdateData(uint16_t *buttons, uint8_t b1, uint8_t b2) 
{
    /* You could also just return the value rather than passing a pointer
     * around like this. Even better, skip this function call and do the
     * math. */
    *buttons = (uint16_t)b1;
    *buttons |= (uint16_t)(b2 << 8);
}

bool get_button_state(uint16_t *buttons, button_t button)
{
    return *buttons & (1 << button);
}

void APP_Send()
{
    uint8_t packet[2];

    packet[0] = (uint8_t)(buttons & 0xff);
    packet[1] = (uint8_t)((buttons >> 8) & 0xff);
}
```

If you're using GCC, you can do the following to make a packed structure:

```
typedef struct __atrribute__((packed)) {

  /**     BYTE 0         **/        
  unsigned       button_1:1;       
  unsigned       button_2:1;
  unsigned       button_3:1;
  unsigned       button_4:1;
  unsigned       button_5:1;
  unsigned       button_6:1;
  unsigned       button_7:1;

  /** And BYTE 2 which I didn't paste to save SO's space lol **/
  // button_9:1 to button_16:1
} FP_BUTTONS;
```

Answer (score 2):

The code has some flaws:

- You write C, but use C++ tag and a C++-signature for APP_Send() (C would require `void` for an empty argument list).
- Bitfields have some problems, mostly here as their ordering is not defined (fields might be allocated top-down or bottom-up - all seen already).
- `(b1 & ( 1 << 1 )) >> 1` will be calculated as `int`. For signed types, right shift is implementation defined. Although it likely works, it is certainly not "defensive programming";-)
- Bits start from 0, not 1. That error of yours is called "of by one" and very common (it might even be one of the most frequent programming errors).
- This code is likely pretty costly, as the compiler might not be able to optimize it to basic instructions.

So, on an embedded system, one normally would just use the `uint8_t` as a bitmap and avoid bitfield structs. This because there is no guarantee these will match the layout of peripheral registers for instance and moving, etc. is pretty annoying and might very well blow your timing (e.g. interrupt handler).

Additionally, using masks allows to manipulate multiple bits at once very easily.

```
enum {
    BIT0 = (1U<<0),
    BIT1 = (1U<<1),
    ...
};   
uint8_t buttons;

... in a function:
buttons |= BIT1 | BIT2;     // set the corresponding bits
buttons &= ~(BIT5 | BIT7);  // clear those bits

if ( buttons & BIT4 )
    ...

GPIOB->OUTR = BIT4 | BIT6;  // set the output bits on STM32F port B
```

That's how it is done actually in embedded programming. Note that the STM32F have 16 bit GPIO ports, not 8 bits.

Oh, and to get a single bit as 0/1 value:

```
int single_bit = !!(buttons & BIT3)
```

This will create a boolean result with the first negation, which is 0 or 1 by the standard. The second negation will make that positive logic again. This is, however, seldom used, the one in the `if ...` above is most times enough.
A good compiler (as gcc) should optimize this pretty well on Cortex-M, however.

The latter you could simply assign to each of your bit-fields. If you're lucky the compiler knows that pattern and creates a simple assignment (or at least just a bitfield-transfer with two instructions).